# How can chemical formulas with '()' be broken down into their constituent elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanto to create constituent elements dataset from chemical formulas.
I was able to break down the chemical formulas without the (), but I am unable to write the code for the ones with the ().

The code without () is below.

```
symbol = ''
comp_list = []
wt_list = []
for c in chemical_formula:
    if c.isupper():
        if len(symbol) != 0:
            comp_list.append(symbol)
            wt_list.append(1)
            symbol = ''
        symbol += c
    elif c.islower():
        symbol += c
    else:
        comp_list.append(symbol)
        wt_list.append(int(c))
        symbol = ''
    
if len(symbol) != 0:
    comp_list.append(symbol)
    wt_list.append(1)

comp_data[atom_cols] = comp_list
comp_data[comp_cols] = wt_list
```

and for example, I want to split chemical formula 'Ti3(SbPd)2' into below.

| M1 | M2 | M3 | M1_num | M2_num | M3_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ti | Sb | Pd | 3 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: You need to manually check for braces since they are considered "lowercase". With your current code a brace will trigger the `elif`. Add above the existing `elif` another condition:  `if c in ['(', ')']: continue`

Comment: @pavel: Parentheses (and braces) aren't considered lowercase. They'll hit the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code inside a function:

```
def chemical(chemical_formula):
  symbol = ''
  comp_list = []
  wt_list = []
  for c in chemical_formula:
      if c.isupper():
          if len(symbol) != 0:
              comp_list.append(symbol)
              wt_list.append(1)
              symbol = ''
          symbol += c
      elif c.islower():
          symbol += c
      else:
          comp_list.append(symbol)
          wt_list.append(int(c))
          symbol = ''
      
  if len(symbol) != 0:
      comp_list.append(symbol)
      wt_list.append(1)
  return(comp_list,wt_list)
```

With this function, I made another function that standardizes formulas with parentheses:

```
def standardization(chemical_formula1):
  comp_list = []
  wt_list = []
  chF = ''
  parentheses = False
  add_parentheses = False
  chemical_formula = ''
  for i in chemical_formula1:
    #===========================================================================
    if i == ')' :
      parentheses = False
      add_parentheses = True
    elif i == '(' :
      parentheses = True
    elif parentheses == True:
      chemical_formula += str(i)
    #===========================================================================
    #Adding the elements inside the '()' while "i" is the number after the ')'
    elif add_parentheses == True:
      #==================== YOUR CODE TO BREAK CHEMICAL FORMULA ================
      comp_list = chemical(chemical_formula)[0]
      wt_list = chemical(chemical_formula)[1]
      #=========================================================================
      for e in range(len(comp_list)):
        chF += str(comp_list[e])
        chF += str((int(wt_list[e]))*int(i))
      add_parentheses = False
    #===========================================================================
    #If we don't have any parentheses, only this "if" will be run every time:===
    elif parentheses == False and add_parentheses == False:
      chF += str(i)
    #===========================================================================
  return(chF)
```

And finally, a function that gives the output in a data frame as you want:

```
import pandas as pd

def output(chemical_formula):
  if '(' in list(chemical_formula):
    chemical_formula = standardization(chemical_formula)
  columns = []
  comp_list = chemical(chemical_formula)[0]
  wt_list = chemical(chemical_formula)[1]
  for i in range(1 , len(comp_list)+1):
    columns.append('M'+str(i))
  for i in range(1 , len(wt_list)+1):
    columns.append('M'+str(i)+'_num')
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
  lst = list(comp_list + wt_list)
  df.loc[0] = lst
  return(df)
```

```
for formula in ['H2O','Cu3(PO4)2','Ti3(SbPd)2','NaCl','Al(OH)3','C3H6O']:
  df = output(formula)
  print(df.to_string(index=False))
  print('-------------------------------')
```

Output:

```
M1 M2 M1_num M2_num
 H  O      2      1
-------------------------------
M1 M2 M3 M1_num M2_num M3_num
Cu  P  O      3      2      8
-------------------------------
M1 M2 M3 M1_num M2_num M3_num
Ti Sb Pd      3      2      2
-------------------------------
M1 M2 M1_num M2_num
Na Cl      1      1
-------------------------------
M1 M2 M3 M1_num M2_num M3_num
Al  O  H      1      3      3
-------------------------------
M1 M2 M3 M1_num M2_num M3_num
 C  H  O      3      6      1
-------------------------------
```